# Parameter input for variables through windows cmd

Tags: r, cmd

I would need help.
I am making a script where it will be programmed as an automatic task in windows. I would need to know what function to use so that when it is run via cmd ask me a question about the parameter to enter and then continue executing it with cmd.

I have tried the readline function and it does not work for me in this case

Comment: Please show us some code with your attempts to use the command `SET /P "A_VAR=Enter the special number: ".` Otherwise, please delete this question here and ask on https://superuser.com/

Comment: Also, what is an "automatic task" in Windows?

Comment: Hello, Sorry I did not explain myself well. When I say an automatic tasca I mean Scheduled Task.
With this Scheduled Task the cmd is executed and I would like to introduce different parameters for the R script

Comment: actually I have:  name<--"Peter" . and I would like to have that when it is run in the cmd ask me what is your name. Enter it in the cmd and make it a variable in R

Comment: If the scheduled task runs at 10:00 each day, do you want something to pop up on the screen to prompt you for the parameter(s)?

Comment: yes. exactly It's what I need

Comment: Please write a simple test script that uses SET /P `"A_VAR=Enter the special number: "` and schedule it. When it runs, what happens? Please add the script and the results to the question.